# Does Json Schema allow a property's definition to reference another property?

Tags: jsonschema, json-schema-validator, ajv

I'd like to create a JSON schema that restricts one property's values based on another property's values.

An example valid object might look like this:

```
{
   "lookup": {
      "foo": "string",
      "bar": "number",
   },
   // properties in `values` must exist in `lookup`
   "values": {
      // `foo` must be a string
      "foo": "string is OK",
      // `bar` must be a number
      "bar": 100
   }
}
```

The idea is for the schema to enforce a relationship between the two properties.

```json
{
"type": "object",
"properties": {
  "lookup" : {
    "type": "object",
    "additionalProperties" : {
      "type": "string",
      "enum": ["string", "number"]
    }
  },
  "values": {
    "type": "object",
    // - this value's properties must exist in `lookup`
    // - if the property in `lookup` is set to `string`, the type here must be `string`; if the property in `lookup` is set to `number`, the type here must be `number`
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible in some cases.  While you can't restrict a piece of data to certain values taken from other parts of the data (for example: using property X to provide a list of values that property Y can have), you can specify conditionals between parts of your schema.

- requirement 1: this value's properties must exist in `lookup` -> not possible
- requirement 2: if the property in `lookup` is set to `string`, the type here must be `string`; if the property in `lookup` is set to `number`, the type here must be `number` -> possible

See https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/conditionals.html for the various options available to you.

Comment: Shouldn't we expect, that both requirements need to be addressed together?

Comment: Based on the example schema given, I would assume the properties in "lookup" are arbitrary. How do you meet requirement 2 in this case?

Answer (score -2):

This is not possible with the standard specification of JSON Schema.